# How can I ignore the outermost level of a JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp

I'm querying the OpenLibrary.org book database, but one quirk of it is that when you request a book by ISBN the results include the ISBN id as the outermost part of the data structure, like so:

{"ISBN:0192821474":  { "stuff I actually care about" }
}

When I generate a wrapper class that gets in the way; it's complicated also because the wrapper class winds up being named ISBN0192821474.  I'm using the "Xamasoft JSON Class Generator" for that.

What I need to be able do to is to "skip" the outermost element and get it's text as the actual content of my response.

What's the best way to do that?  I have Newtonsoft.Json and RestSharp and am hoping I can somehow "walk" the structure one level deeper and work from there.

In the following code, for example, it would work nicely if response.Content were the contents of the child node.

```
        var client = new RestClient("http://openlibrary.org");
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0192821474&jscmd=data&format=json", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
        var x   = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example.OpenLibrary>(response.Content);
```

I'm sure I could write a regular expression to parse it, but clearly that's not the "right" way to do it, so I need some guidance.

Comment: Here is some documentation from Newtonsoft (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm) gives a clear example of how to do it :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this easily using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects).

I would make a little reusable helper method like this:

```
public static T DeserializeAndUnwrap<T>(string json)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    return jo.Properties().First().Value.ToObject<T>();
}
```

Here is a demo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://openlibrary.org");
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:0192821474&jscmd=data&format=json", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        Book book = DeserializeAndUnwrap<Book>(content);
        Console.WriteLine(book.title);
        if (book.authors.Any()) Console.WriteLine("By " + book.authors.First().name);
        Console.WriteLine(book.number_of_pages + " pages");
        Console.WriteLine("Published " + book.publish_date);
    }

    public static T DeserializeAndUnwrap<T>(string json)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
        return jo.Properties().First().Value.ToObject<T>();
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public Publisher[] publishers { get; set; }
    public string pagination { get; set; }
    public Identifiers identifiers { get; set; }
    public Classifications classifications { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public int number_of_pages { get; set; }
    public Subject[] subjects { get; set; }
    public string publish_date { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public Author[] authors { get; set; }
    public string by_statement { get; set; }
    public Publish_Places[] publish_places { get; set; }
}

public class Identifiers
{
    public string[] lccn { get; set; }
    public string[] openlibrary { get; set; }
    public string[] isbn_10 { get; set; }
    public string[] oclc { get; set; }
    public string[] librarything { get; set; }
    public string[] goodreads { get; set; }
}

public class Classifications
{
    public string[] dewey_decimal_class { get; set; }
}

public class Publisher
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Publish_Places
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
The anthropic cosmological principle
By John D. Barrow
706 pages
Published 1996
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LGiztM